# Jbasic (jBC) source code line Continuation Character?

Tags: jbase

Does anyone know if jBase Basic (jBC or JBasic) programming language has a line Continuation Character?

I have a jBasic Program that contain an if statement that is over 80 characters in length but my code standards say my code requires to fit within a 80 character line length.

Qbasic uses the underscore (_) as a continuation character.

I have searched for info on the jBase website but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have a long line of code in JBC (jBase Basic) that you want to divide across multiple lines. This can be done with backslash char "\":

```
IF YR.VALUE.DATE LE R.ACCOUNT<AC.CAP.DATE.CR.INT, 1> \
OR YR.VALUE.DATE LE R.ACCOUNT<AC.CAP.DATE.DR.INT, 1> THEN
    COMI = "SOME VALUE"
END
```

However, this does not work in the TAFJ, only in JBC and TAFC.

Here is a link from Temenos site:
http://jbc.temenos.com/pages/to_wrap_a_long_line.html